# Codeigniter error message Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this error message when i run my php CodeIgniter project:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\AppServ\www\tree\application\models\mtree.php:17)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 442

line 17:

```
echo $row->members_id . "</br>";
```

this is my model function:

```
function convert_all() {
    $this->db->empty_table('table1');
    $this->db->empty_table('table2');
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `table1` (`members_id`, `members_username`);
    $query = $this->db->get('table2');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->members_id > 1) {
            echo $row->members_id . "</br>";
        }
        if ($this->isadvanced($row->members_id, $row->members_direct_id)) {
            $this->insert_to_right($row, $row->members_direct_id);
        } else {
            $this->insert_to_left($row, $row->members_direct_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You're missing quotes at the end of this statement: *$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `table1` (`members_id`, `members_username`);*

Comment: Error caused by some content being sent to the user **before the call** to `header` function. The code you gave does not provide enough information to aid debugging. Read more about the error: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Comment: thanks shuvo for helping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While using codeigniter, its best recommended that you `echo` only in views.

Echoing anywhere randomly sends some data to browser, after which you can't modify headers (this includes attempt to redirect, set content-type, etc)

You should re-organize your code, such that, `echo` are done within views only. This will solve your header issues in Codeigniter.

This also includes extra whitespaces at the end after the closing brace "`} ?>`" in non-view php files.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display anything before the header function is called. You should not display anything form model or controller to avoid this kind of error. If you want to display something form the controller or model then you should store the output to the buffer instead of sending it to the browser. You can store the output to the buffer using `ob_start()` function before `header()` function is called. Then you can do something like this

```
if(true)
{
    header("Location:http://google.com");
}
else
{
   ob_end_flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be helpfull
Use `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();` instead of `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` in your `Application/config/config.php` file

Answer (score 0):

this was your issue - echo $row->members_id . ""; -- as the above answers say, don't echo something in your controllers, push to do it in the views - always